# How to mock imwrite in a loop

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to use Python unittest library to test the following code.

```
from cv2 import imwrite
import h5py
import lumpy as np

class Myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def load_data(self, path):
        count = 10
        for i in range(count):
            mat_file = path + f'{i}.mat'
            with h5py.File(mat_file, 'r') as fin:
                data = np.array(fin['data'])

            for j in range(len(data)):
                filename = path + f'{i}_{j}.jpg'
                imwrite(filename, data)

        self.data = data
```

I tried to do the following. But I am getting AttributeError saying Myclass has no attribute 'imwrite'. And I do not know how to mock the nested loops with image writing `imwrite`.

```
from mock import MagicMock, patch

def test():
    m = MagicMock()
    m.__enter__.return_value = data

    with patch("h5py.File", return_value=m):
        with patch(Myclass.imwrite) as mock_imwrite:
            testclass = Myclass()
            testclass.load_data(path='test')
            assert testclass.get_data() == data
```

I hope someone can help me out. Any help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that your class `Myclass` does not have a function `imwrite`. Only the module (aka the file the class is defined in) is aware of this function.

If you want to patch the `imwrite` function of the package `cv2`, you have to write:

(untested code)

```
with patch('cv2.imwrite') as mock_imwrite:
   testclass = Myclass()
   ...
```

But the `as mock_imwrite` part is only needed, if you run an `assert` on the mock. Otherwise, you may just skip it.